# Icons are uncentered in taskbar buttons in Lxpanel

Tags: appearance, lxpanel

I use Lxpanel 0.10.1 on Ubuntu 21.04. The taskbar is set to show **icons only**, but as seen below the icons are not centered in the buttons, but displaced to the left.

[image: Lxpanel icons]

Is there any way to make then centered by, say, adding a left margin to each button? I have tried all the permutations of the "disable enlargement", "show task icons smaller" options, tweaked the "spacing" and "maximum width" of the task bar preferences to no avail.

Below the Global and Taskbar sections of the configuration file: `~/.config/lxpanel/default/panels/panel`.

```
Global {
  edge=bottom
  allign=left
  margin=0
  widthtype=percent
  width=100
  height=24
  transparent=1
  tintcolor=#000080
  alpha=255
  setdocktype=1
  setpartialstrut=1
  usefontcolor=1
  fontcolor=#00fff9
  usefontsize=1
  fontsize=10
  background=0
  backgroundfile=/usr/share/lxpanel/images/background.png
  align=left
  iconsize=24
}
Plugin {
  type=taskbar
  expand=1
  Config {
    tooltips=-1
    IconsOnly=-1
    AcceptSkipPager=1
    ShowIconified=1
    ShowMapped=1
    ShowAllDesks=0
    UseMouseWheel=0
    UseUrgencyHint=-1
    FlatButton=0
    MaxTaskWidth=10
    spacing=1
    GroupedTasks=0
    DisableUpscale=0
    UseSmallerIcons=-1
    SameMonitorOnly=0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed it with [Fbpanel](http://aanatoly.github.io/fbpanel/docs.html). The taskbar configuration contain `IconsOnly = true`:

```
Plugin {
    type = taskbar
    config {
        ShowMapped = true
        IconsOnly = true
    }
}
```