# Is it possible to use different color for a minimized window taskbar button? Any theme that does?

Tags: themes, taskbar, button, minimize, gtk-2

I use Fbpanel as my panel. It uses GTK2 for theming. I would like to know which windows are minimized by a quick glance at the taskbar.

Below, GIMP's icon background is green because GIMP has focus, but there is no indication that Xeyes (the right button) is minimized.

[image]

I tried literally dozens of themes but none would color minimized window buttons in a special way. I hope this is not impossible in GTK2 (I'd be surprised because urgent windows icons even flash!).

I tried other panels as well but [found issues with them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336096/icons-are-uncentered-in-taskbar-buttons-in-lxpanel/1336242#1336242), so if possible I'd like to stick with Fbpanel.

Comment: I can't think of a single operating system that does what you seek. You could get the source code and modify the task bar. Personally I would rather highlight icons for windows that are off the screen canvas and a right click option to move them to the visible area.